# Expression must have a constant value when trying to create a string

Tags: c, string, file, constants

I have a file which I want 20% the length of his string, so I first found the full length of his and then found the 20%, now I want to create a string which it's size is that 20%. I wrote this part of code:

```
int findres=0;
    int len, partlen;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    partlen = (len * 20) / 100;
    char temp[partlen];
    while ((fgets(temp, partlen, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fs, "%s INFECTED\n", fname);
            findres++;
        }
    }
```

Now' it won't let me compile because it says I can't put partlen as the size of temp, because partlen is not constant, I couldn't figure out a way to fix this.

Comment: `char *temp = malloc(partlen)`.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It's either 15+ years old, or being invoked in antique mode, or microsoft

Comment: Use C99 or dynamically allocate memory.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Matt McNabb First time I've shared a comment with the same - to the sec - time-stamp.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: @AlanAu Thanks it worked for checking the first 20% of the file, but how do I check the last 20%? What I mean is for example the string length is 100, so the first 20% is 0-19, and I want to check the last 20%, 80-99 how do I do that.

Answer (score -1):

In C, the storage of an array is allocated in compile time and it is located to the stack section of the executable file. The size of the array in your code is determined in the run-time, therefore; it is an error.

You have to use dynamic memory allocation functions which are malloc,calloc and realloc in standarts.

```
char *pStr; /* A pointer to keep the start address of the allocated memory in run-time */
pStr = malloc( sizeof(char) * partlen );
```

After that you must control the return value of the malloc.

Comment: Note that the latest C standard has the ability to handle variable length items, so compiling under the lastest standard, the original posted code would compile.

Comment: the expression 'sizeof(char)' is always 1, so has not effect, clutter the code, and should be removed

Comment: Compiling under the latest C standard `C11` optionally  allows variable length  arrays.  Compiling under its predecessor, the 16 year-old `C99` allows  variable length  arrays. "size of the array in your code is determined in the run-time" is not generally always true.

Comment: @user3629249 i assumed that if someone takes such an error, compiler must not support latest standart in default. Writing "In C," is wrong as you said, it should be "In C89". I will be careful about that.